# Logical operators in if block from cell content

Tags: vba, excel, operators

I have a cell "<" operator value in D8.

In my macro code, I want to compare some data like that:

```
if(e<10) then
    msgbox "less than 10"
Endif
```

After, when I change cell D8 from "<" to ">", the macro code must run like that:

```
if(e>10) then
    msgbox "greater than 10"
Endif
```

Summary,
when I change the value of D8 "<" or ">", the code must compare like I want.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) can be used in your code to process a operation described by a constructed string.

```
Sub eval_test()
    Dim e As Long

    e = 9
    Range("D8") = "<"
    Debug.Print e & Range("D8").Value & 10

    If Application.Evaluate(e & Range("D8").Value & 10) Then
        MsgBox "e is " & Range("D8").Value & " 10"
    Else
        MsgBox "e is not " & Range("D8").Value & " 10"
    End If

End Sub
```